# Any way to override properties-maven-plugin's set-system-properties by -Dpropname=value on the command line?

Tags: java, maven

Is there any way to override properties-maven-plugin's set-system-properties by -Dpropname=value on the command line? In other words: to set system properties only if they have not been set already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go via a regular property:

```
<properties>
    <propname>Default Value</propname>
</properties>

...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>system.property.name</name>
                        <value>${propname}</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then run with `-Dpropname="Specified Value"`.

Comment: hmmm, at least it did not work here in comination with jetty and surefire maven plugins where I use an environment variable to define the environment (prod/devel).